# Angular & TypeScript - Displaying the Last Date of the Current Month

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular5

In my **Angular** 5 project, I need to display the **last date of the current month**. I have tried several techniques but none of them gives me the right answer. Though solutions are available for JavaScript, somehow it doesn't work in TypeScript.

HTML:

```
<button class = "btn btn-sm btn-outline primary" (click) = "selectThisMonth()" >This Month</button>
<pre> Last Date of Month: {{ toDate | json }} </pre>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDateStruct, NgbCalendar} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
const now = new Date();
@Component({
selector: 'app',
templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    fromDate: NgbDateStruct;
    toDate: NgbDateStruct;
    constructor (calendar: NgbCalendar){
        this.fromDate = calendar.getToday();
        this.toDate = calendar.getNext(calendar.getToday(), 'd', 10);
    }
    selectThisMonth() {
        this.toDate = {year: now.getFullYear(), month: now.getMonth+1, day: now.getDate()};
    }
}
```

If there was any working solution in TypeScript, please suggest.

The Expected Output should display "**April 30 2018**" as 30 is the Last Date of the current month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the JS solution and paste it into the NgbDateStruct:

```
selectThisMonth() {
    let year = now.getFullYear();
    let month = now.getMonth()+1;
    let day = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    this.toDate = {year: year, month: month, day: day};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the last date as

```
selectThisMonth() {
        this.toDate = {year: now.getFullYear(), month: now.getMonth+1, day: 0};
}
```

I tried in native js

```
var a = new Date();
var b = new Date(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth()+1, 0); // Mon Apr 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
var b = new Date(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth()+2, 0); // Thu May 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

Comment: Also how will I differentiate if it was April or May

Comment: from month of the current date

Comment: For that we will be using if..else... But is there any way using the builtins to find out the last date of the month...just like there are builtin methods to find the current date, month etc

Comment: the approach I suggest is set  the next month without a day - 
var b = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth()+1). It should return the first day of a month. In your case try additionally set day as -1 -> var b = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth()+1, -1) perhaps it 'll help

Comment: Use the angular 5 date pipe to display your date. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

```
const firstDay = new NgbDate(today.year, today.month, 1); //First day of the current month

//Last day of the current month
const lastDay = this.calendar.getPrev(this.calendar.getNext(firstDay, 'm', 1), 'd', 1);

console.log('First day of the current month: ', firstDay);
console.log('Last day of the current month: ', lastDay);
```